# Expansion of power of a linear operator's kernel is nonincreasing

Tags: linear-algebra, functional-analysis

The rate of expansion of kernel of power of linear operator is nonincreasing, with respect to dimension. To be more specific, let $V$ be a vector space over field $\mathbb{F}$, and $T$ is a linear operator on $V$. Then for any positive integer $m$,
$$
\dim \text{ker}\, T^{m+1} - \dim \text{ker}\, T^{m} \leq \dim \text{ker}\, T^{m} - \dim \text{ker}\, T^{m-1}.
$$
Is this true? If not, what additional conditions should be applied to make this true?

Comment: @kavi Algebraic. It's difference of dimension.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will give a proof for the finite dimensional case for the sake of presentation simplicity , but the reasoning is valid for the general case. Assume $m\ge 1$ and
$$\dim \ker T^{m+1}=N,\ \dim\ker T^m=N-n$$ Let $$\{v_1,\ldots v_n,v_{n+1}\ldots, v_N\}$$ denote the linear basis of $\ker T^{m+1}$ such that $v_{n+1}\,\ldots, v_N$ is a linear basis of $\ker T^m.$ Then the elements $Tv_1,\ldots, Tv_n$ belong to $\ker T^m\setminus\ker T^{m-1}$ and are linearly independent. Indeed, assume for a contradiction that
$$\lambda_1Tv_1+\ldots +\lambda_n Tv_n=0$$ Then
$$T^m(\lambda_1v_1+\ldots\lambda_nv_n)=\lambda_1T^mv_1+\ldots +\lambda_n T^mv_n=0$$ Thus $\lambda_1v_1+\ldots +\lambda_nv_n\in \ker T^m,$ hence $\lambda_1v_1+\ldots +\lambda_nv_n=0,$ i.e. $\lambda_1=\ldots=\lambda_n=0.$ This shows that
$$\dim\ker T^m-\dim\ker T^{m-1}\ge n=\dim\ker T^{m+1}-\dim\ker T^{m}$$